# Scrapy DropItem for URL that contains a substring

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, pipeline

I'm very new to Python, and I'm using scrapy. Right now, I have two spiders, one for Google, and one for the pages themselves. I plan to combine them, but haven't yet because I want to troubleshoot the pages separately. Both spiders work fine, but I want to be able to drop internal links from my list of scraped links (so those that contain a '#' symbol). I've tried this a million different ways, including using find & regex, changing variable names, not using variables, adding "self" to the expression, but nothing seems to affect it. The pipeline is enabled -- it just doesn't seem to do anything. Any help is appreciated.

pipelines.py

```
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem

class SpiderValidationPipeline:
    def drop_links(self, item, spider):
        url = str(item.get('links'))
        marker = '#'

        if item.get('links'):
            if marker in url:
                raise DropItem("Internal Link")
        else:
            return item
```

items.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst, MapCompose
from w3lib.html import remove_tags

def remove_nt(text):
    return text.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('[edit]', '').replace('/sæs/', '').replace('\"', '')\
        .replace('\u2014', '—')

class GoogleCrawlItem(scrapy.Item):

    title = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags), output_processor=TakeFirst())
    link = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags), output_processor=TakeFirst())
    desc = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags), output_processor=TakeFirst())

class PageCrawlItem(scrapy.Item):

    title = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags), output_processor=TakeFirst())
    meta = scrapy.Field()
    h1 = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags))
    h2 = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, remove_nt))
    h3 = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, remove_nt))
    h4 = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, remove_nt))
    paragraph = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags, remove_nt))
    links = scrapy.Field(input_processor=MapCompose(remove_tags))
```

pagespider.py

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from google_crawl.items import PageCrawlItem

class PageSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'page'
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service']

    def parse(self, response):

        for meta_element in response.css('head'):
            page_item = ItemLoader(item=PageCrawlItem(), selector=meta_element)

            page_item.add_css('title', 'title')
            page_item.add_css('meta', 'meta')

            yield page_item.load_item()

        for par_item in response.css('body'):
            par_item = ItemLoader(item=PageCrawlItem(), selector=par_item)

            par_item.add_css('paragraph', 'p')
            par_item.add_css('h1', 'h1')

            yield par_item.load_item()

        for h2s in response.css('body'):
            h2_item = ItemLoader(item=PageCrawlItem(), selector=h2s)

            h2_item.add_css('h2', 'h2')

            yield h2_item.load_item()

        for h3s in response.css('body'):
            h3_item = ItemLoader(item=PageCrawlItem(), selector=h3s)

            h3_item.add_css('h3', 'h3')

            yield h3_item.load_item()

        for h4s in response.css('body'):
            h4_item = ItemLoader(item=PageCrawlItem(), selector=h4s)

            h4_item.add_css('h4', 'h4')

            yield h4_item.load_item()

        for links in response.css('body'):
            link_item = ItemLoader(item=PageCrawlItem(), selector=links)

            link_item.add_css('links', 'a::attr(href)')

            yield link_item.load_item()
```

settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'google_crawl'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['google_crawl.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'google_crawl.spiders'

USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False

DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 7

ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'google_crawl.pipelines.SpiderValidationPipeline': 100,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your spider is setup right now, you yield all of your "links" in one list in in one item. The method in your pipeline would only work if the links field in the item was a string.

Another problem is the method name in your pipeline needs to be changed to `process_item` for it to work with the `scrapy` api. Additionally since your items don't output the "links" key, you need to test to make sure that field is present in the item before attempting to filter out unwanted URLs.

For example just make these alterations:

##### pipeline.py

```py
class SpiderValidationPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if "links" in item:
            item["links"] = [i for i in item.get("links") if "#" not in i]
        return item
```

Comment: That worked!! And I appreciate the explanation -- it makes so much sense. Thank you so much! And apologies it took me so long to respond. I'm very grateful for your help!!